# Getting the number of visible columns in a ListGrid in SmartGWT?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to get the number of visible columns ([ListGridField](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html)) in a [ListGrid](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html).

Is there an easy solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution using [`ListGrid.fieldIsVisible(String fieldName)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#fieldIsVisible%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
private int getNumVisibleColumns(ListGrid grid) {
    int count = 0;
    for (ListGridField field : grid.getFields()) {
        if (grid.fieldIsVisible(field.getName())) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: When you say the field is hidden. Do you mean ListGridField.hidden is true ? I am trying to do the same thing. But it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

you can loop through the columns in the ListGrid and call ListGridField.getHidden() to count which ones are visible or not.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no such method as `getHidden()` in the _ListGridField_ class.[link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html)
However, I came up with a solution.